# How to get SMS delivery daily report from salesforce marketing cloud using REST or SOAP APIs

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud, exacttarget

I am trying to build an automated pipeline to get below Marketing Cloud KPIs (daily basis)

- SMS "sents" and "NumberDelivered"
- Email Object - sends, bounce, delivered, opened, clicked

I was able to do the same for Email object using python FuelSDK (as shown below), but I could not find anything similar for SMS Sends.

```
    stubObj = FuelSDK.ET_Client(False, debug)
    req = FuelSDK.ET_Send()
    req.auth_stub = stubObj
    req.search_filter = {'Property' : 'SendDate','SimpleOperator' : 'greaterThanOrEqual','Value' : '2021-01-01'}
    getResponse = req.get()
```

Thanks in advance!